# Angular 2 (click) with unknown html tags

Tags: dom, angular

The `(click)` event isnt fired on the component controller of the template:

```
<Shape *ng-for="#c of coords" inner-html="{{c.ts}}" 
    (click)="shapeSelected(t.subShapeID)"
    attr.shapeid="{{c.subShapeID}}" render="true" onmouseover="enter(this)" 
    onmouseout="leave(this)" isPickable="true">  </Shape>
```

Shape is here an X3dom element (no angular2 component).

Edit: this works with standard html tags e.g.

```
 <tr *ng-for="#t of coords" (click)="shapeSelected(t.subShapeID)">
                <td style="padding:0px 10px;">Shape</td>
                <td>{{t.subShapeID}}</td>
 </tr>
```

How is it possible with unknown html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess console is not defined inside template. Try creating method in shape component which will execute console.log()

Comment: that is not the problem. I tried also a function of the component controller. the (click) attribute is not visible in DOM!

Comment: What do you mean by not visible in DOM? DOM preview in dev tools? If so then yes, you don't see it there.

Bear in mind that onmouseout and onmouseover are also events so parenthesis is mandatory. Also they should be named mouseout and mouseover.

Also check what version of angular do you use. alpha 52 use *ngFor instade of *ng-for

Comment: the problem has to do with the html tag. With standard html tags it works. Please see edited question

Comment: where do you define shapeSelected method. in first case it should be in Shape component. In second in component that is a container for tr

Comment: `shapeSelected` is defined in the component controller of the template. I have no shape component. It is an X3dom node.

Comment: let's streighten things up, shapeSelected is working. But 
    <Shape *ng-for="#c of coords" (click)="console.log(1)"
doesn't.
If Shape is a componenet from different lib you can't use it as is because Angular doesn't know about it. You have to create a Shape component yourself and add custom methods inside.

Comment: no, that is not the problem. I edited the question once again

Comment: So as I wrote, if Shape is from different lib you have to create your own, custom element to wrap it up. You can't add events to X3dom Shape element because angular doesn't recognize it.